# What does it mean to "end up with a Desmond"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am reading a (fictional) story set in 1980's Scotland. One of the characters is studying (reading?) business and this is written:

> he could tell the class of honours was not something she cared about and so it proved. She ended up with a Desmond and was done with academia forever.

What does it mean to "end up with a Desmond"?

Comment: Source? Title of  book?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that Desmond is implied to be a dodo (extinct/worthless).

Comment: It's a form of rhyming slang. In rhyming slang, a particular word is used as a substitute for a different word. For example, in Cockney rhyming slang the word *apples* is used as a substitute for the word *stairs*. The substitute word is known to be the first word in a two or three word phrase. So the word *apples* is understood to be the first word in the phrase *apples and pears.* The last word in this 2 or 3 word phrase rhymes with the word that is being replaced. So you'll notice that the word *pears* rhymes with the word *stairs.* (continued)

Comment: Sometimes a speaker will use the whole phrase as a substitute for the word that's being replaced. So someone might say "She went up the **apples and pears**" to mean "She went up the **stairs**". However, usually the speaker will just use the first word in the phrase and not the rest of it (so the rhyming word is not actually pronounced). So instead of saying "She went up the apples and pears" a speaker is more likely to say "She went up the apples". In your case the word being replaced is *two-two* (2nd class degree), the substitute phrase is *Desmond Tutu*, the replacement word is *Desmond*.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It means to get a II-2 degree. Pronounced Two-two. Not a fail, not a III: but in practice very low. Desmond Tutu was a famous South African Archbishop. It is a bad-taste joke.

Thaks to @anything here is a reference:

[A very concise dictionary of student slang](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2012/sep/18/concise-dictionary-of-student-slang)

Comment: Beat me to it. Here is a source: https://www.theguardian.com/education/2012/sep/18/concise-dictionary-of-student-slang.

Comment: For completeness, a first (the highest degree) is a Damien (rhyming slang for artist Damien Hirst); in the past, footballer Geoff Hurst would have been used instead. Attila (the Hun) for a II-1, a good if not outstanding result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially so quickly! In the interest of completion for a clueless American, is there an explanation of UK university grades and what they mean?

Comment: @aghast Various conversion tables between UK degree classifications and US GPAs exist, and they don't all agree with each other: [here's one](https://www.grb.uk.com/recruiter-research/international-degree-equivalents).

Comment: Desmond is (or was) _much_ more common than Damien/Geoff or Attila.  I don't think I have heard either of those.  UK University honours degrees go First, Two-one, Two-two, Third.  An ordinary degree is ranked even lower than a Third.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica agreed, I think I’ve heard Damien in the wild only once, and never the others, while “a Desmond” was reasonably common. Maybe some kind of stigma/superstition against speaking the lower degree out loud?

Comment: Is it really considered that bad-taste?  I don't think it's implying that Desmond Tutu would've gotten poor marks, it's just having some fun with his name.  As rhyming slang goes, I've heard much more clearly offensive examples than that...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, yes, it seems in perfectly good taste, especially compared to calling someone a “Berkshire Hunk” or “berk”.

Comment: @aghast A good working characterisation would be that a first generally means someone is smart and worked hard; at the opposite end a third means they likely did little work. A 2.1 has typically been the threshold for lots of 'professional' grad schemes and prestigious jobs, and a 2.2 would not normally be embarrassing (the way a third would typically be) but would make it harder if the holder wanted to quickly get into a high-paying job.

Comment: @aghast While on the subject of British universities for the American perspective, be aware that these grades will typically be awarded on the basis of final exams at the end of a three-year degree, perhaps incorporating a project or something like that, and perhaps incorporating exams from the end of the second year too. There is not the same tradition of continuous assessment contributing to a final grade as there is in the American GPA system.

Comment: There's nothing bad taste about this rhyming slang at all.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I didn't read the answer as saying that the use of rhyming slang was bad taste, just that the passage laughing at her lack of academic success is a bad taste joke. It would be just as much so had it said II-2 directly

Comment: @Tristan Ah, I see +1. I think you're right there. I don't think it *is* meant as a joke, though. It's just a description of what happened!

Comment: @MichaelLorton Hunk? I think you mean Berkshire Hunt.

Comment: @Ottie There's also "plough" for a fail, which definitely does have a superstition against speaking it out loud: <https://web.archive.org/web/20120414185850/http://www.girton.cam.ac.uk/about/college-history/college-songs/tripos-song/>

Comment: Wikipedia has a decent summary of the grades, which might be worth linking to in the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_undergraduate_degree_classification (It also mentions the rhyming slang, although I've personally never heard it before, despite having a degree myself.)

Comment: Also used in a sporting context for a match ending two all, or 2-2.

Comment: @mjaggard — yes, “Hunt” and it’s too late to fix it.